# Issue with edittext

Tags: android

I'm new in java and I have problem with converting "input" to string.

```
input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wpiszZapytanie);
String zapytanieDoUrl = input.getText().toString();
```

It crashes with this log:

```
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.qm.mood/eu.qm.mood.GIFActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at eu.qm.mood.GIFActivity.onCreate(GIFActivity.java:18)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
10-10 23:57:48.589 9423-9423/eu.qm.mood E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

As I can see there is nothing (null) somewhere. I understand it that this code can't see what's in textbox, what user typed.

Edittext is in content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/welcome" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wpiszZapytanie"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:id="@+id/doit"
        android:onClick="goClick"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wpiszZapytanie"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is activity_gif.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="eu.qm.mood.GIFActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/GifResulttwo"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your xml?

Comment: I believe that the EditText view is null itself for some reason. Are you sure you've inflated your layout right?

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` variable is null that is why you are getting the exception.

Possible reasons:

- I think you are using the wrong `id` for EditText. Check your xml if there is a `EditText` element with the id `wpiszZapytanie`
- You might be inflating the wrong xml layout which does not have an `EditText` with id `wpiszZapytanie`
- You might be doing `findViewById(R.id.wpiszZapytanie);` before `setContentView()` as pointed out by @Pyrodante

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by pgitu: input is null, this happens when the findViewById look fails to find what it is it is looking for. A major cause of this is calling this before calling setContentView.

You cannot access UI elements before the UI is set up. So if those two above aren't it, perhaps this is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your GIFActivity is following this logic on your onCreate method.

```
public class GIFActivity extends Activity {
EditText input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //First
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gif);//Second
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wpiszZapytanie);//Third

        String text = input.getText().toString();
    }   
}
```

activity_gif.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/wpiszZapytanie"/>    

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I haven't mentioned that edittext "wpiszZapytanie" is in content_main.xml not "activity_gif.xml"

Comment: I was just assuming it was named "activity_gif.xml". You should really post your XML so we can better asses what your problem is.